# Sabre Restful API: Question related to booking class and married segments

Tags: rest, sabre

Why the segments "booking code" and "availabilityBreak" are displayed under "passengerInfoList", for each passenger type in part?

Bargain Finder Max REST Response:

`[...]pricingInformation[]->fare->passengerInfoList[]->passengerInfo->fareComponents[]->segments[]->segment->(bookingCode|availabilityBreak)`

---

I would expect those values to be displayed just under segments, not for each passenger in part, because during itinerary revalidation, the Sabre API asks for just one booking class for each segment (not for each passenger type), so which booking class should I indicate if I have three different passenger types (I would expect that the booking classes may be different)?

Revalidate Itinerary Request:

`OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ->OriginDestinationInformation[]->TPA_Extensions->Flight->ClassOfService`

---

And during the creation of PNR, the Sabre API asks for "MarriageGrp" for each segment in part (not for each segment and passenger type). As I understand it, I need to check the "availabilityBreak" (from the search response) to know which segment is a married one (I) and which one is not (O). And again, there are different "availabilityBreak" for each segment and each passenger.

Create Passenger Name Record Request:

`CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ->AirBook->OriginDestinationInformation->FlightSegment[]->MarriageGrp`